# Oracle 19c runInstaller reports PRVF-5311 while checking SSH connectivity

Tags: oracle

I am trying to install Oracle 19c RAC on three nodes, running RHEL 8.3. GRID installation was ok. But, Oracle DB SW install using runInstaller(GUI) is stuck with this issue while checking for SSH connectivity between nodes.

Error Reported:
Cause - Either passwordless SSH connectivity is not setup between specified node(s) or they are not reachable. Refer to the logs for more details.  Action - Refer to the logs for more details or contact Oracle Support Services.  More Details
PRVF-5311 : File "/tmp/InstallActions2020-12-24_01-17-15PM/xyzsvr.getFileInfo184599.out" either does not exist or is not accessible on node "xyzsvr".

When I tried runcluvfy, it reports ok.

$ /u01/app/19.0.0/grid/runcluvfy.sh comp admprv -n xyzsvr1,xyzsvr2,xyzsvr3 -o user_equiv -sshonly -verbose

Verifying User Equivalence ...
Node Name                             Status

---

xyzsvr2                              passed
xyzsvr3                             passed

Verifying Checking user equivalence for user "oracle" on all cluster nodes ...PASSED

From node     To node                   Status

---

xyzsvr2      xyzsvr1                  SUCCESSFUL
xyzsvr2      xyzsvr3                 SUCCESSFUL
xyzsvr3     xyzsvr1                  SUCCESSFUL
xyzsvr3     xyzsvr2                  SUCCESSFUL
Verifying User Equivalence ...PASSED

Verification of administrative privileges was successful.

CVU operation performed:      administrative privileges
Date:                         Dec 24, 2020 1:44:57 PM
CVU home:                     /u01/app/19.0.0/grid/
User:                         oracle

There is nothing in Oracle support site.

Answer (score 1):

Try below solution from https://dbaclass.com/article/upgrade-grid-infrastructure-from-oracle-12c-to-19c:

- Find out where is the scp executable file is located and rename it:

  ```
  mv /usr/bin/scp /usr/bin/scp.orig
  ```
- Create a new file:

  ```
  vi /usr/bin/scp
  ```
- Add the below line to the new created file:

  ```
  /usr/bin/scp.orig -T $*
  ```
- Change the file permission:

  ```
  chmod 555 /usr/bin/scp
  ```
- Once installation is done, you can revert to the original:

  ```
  mv /usr/bin/scp.orig /usr/bin/scp
  ```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900760/what-is-pseudo-tty-allocation-ssh-and-github explains the purpose of the -T parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Oracle support Useful link with this workaround : INS-06006 GI RunInstaller Fails If OpenSSH Is Upgraded to 8.x (Doc ID 2555697.1) https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2555697.1

Comment: Please post the essence here, otherwise your answer will get deleted

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/198906)